# AWS Client VPN - outbound traffic rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn-client

I've set up an AWS Client VPN to remotely connect to a VPC within my AWS network.

Using this VPN, I am able to initiate remote TCP connections from my PC to an EC2 instance.

I also have a scenario when I want to connect in the reverse direction....EC2 instance to PC.   This doesnt work at all and I cant seem to figure out what I need to add to get this to work. I see the packet leave the EC2 instance but it never arrives on my pc.

I have entries in my security group and network ACL right now to allow all inbound/outbound traffic so I think my issue is with the route table?    I was thinking I need to add route for my VPN client CIDR block but I dont know what to use as a Target.

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I used client VPN a couple of years ago but never connected outbound EC2 to PC. If packets get in OK I don't think it's routing, it's more likely to be security group, or perhaps it's by design. If you can't get it working a VPN set up within the VPC console might be more applicable, but it's more difficult to set up on the PC side.